# Django: Mixed managed and raw db commits - TransactionManagementError

Tags: sql, django, commit

I'm writing a bulk insert script using Django's ORM + custom raw SQL. The code has the following outline:

```
import sys, os
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from my_project import settings
from my_project.my_app.models import Model1, Model2
setup_environ(settings)
from django.db import transaction
from django.db import connection

@transaction.commit_manually
def process_file(relevant_file):

    data_file = open(relevant_file,'r')

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    while 1:
        line = data_file.readline()
        if line == '':
            break

        if not(input_row_i%1000):
            transaction.commit()

        if ([some rare condition]):
            model_1 = Model1([Some assignments based on line])
            model_1.save()

        values = [Some values based on line]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `table_1` ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3') VALUES (%i, %f, %s)", values)

    data_file.close()
    transaction.commit()
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't missed to include some condition in the sample code, that would cause the last commit() to not be run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a workaround - place a `transaction.commit()` right after the `model_1.save()`. I think you need to isolate raw and ORM transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [transaction.commit_unless_managed()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

I've written a [post](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/django-mixing-managed-transactions-raw.html) to explain in greater detail with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this exception in a similar circumstance. The django ORM was actually throwing a django.core.exceptions.ValidationError error because a date was incorrectly formatted. Because I was using manual transaction processing to batch database writes, the Django transactions processing code was trying to cleanup inside the raised django.core.exceptions.ValidationError exception and threw it's own exception of django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError. Try a try / except around your model_1 code to see if any other exceptions are being thrown. Something like:

```
try:
    model_1 ...
    model_1.save()
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    print 'line:', line
```

to see if there are any problems with the input data to object creation code.